# How does the use of find command result in a permission denied error?

Tags: linux, unix, find

Please have a look at my code:

```
apple@apples-MacBook-Pro ~ % find ./ -name Desktop -type d   
.//Desktop
find: .//Documents/Library: Permission denied
```

Would someone explain to me what does the second line mean? Why is it in the output?
":find .//Documents/Library:Permission denied"

edit: delete the second question and ask it in a new post.

Comment: I have made changes as requested.

Comment: The user that's running the command doesn't have access to the Library folder.

Comment: But I am the owner!If I don't, who does?  Also, why would find command print that out? It just clusters everything on my screen. Is there a way to suppress that?

Comment: `man find`, type a single `/` and then `-perm`, press ENTER. Now hit `n`, for "next"... read the text that appears, you might find something useful.